# NiFi - Clear PutDatabaseRecord Table Schema Cache

Tags: apache-nifi

Could anyone suggest how to clear PutDatabaseRecord processor table schema cache. We've changed some of our tables (removed columns) but NiFi still uses old schemas and throws errors for columns that no longer exist. We tried to restart a processor multiple times, tried to restart DbcpConnectionPool - all without success.

To me this is the extremely weird behavior.

Thanks in advance

Comment: NiFi official document does not mention anywhere that `PutDatabaseRecord` or `DBCPConnectionPool` caches anything for better performance. Please check a few points - if possible try to delete and recreate `DBCPConnectionPool` with different name;  are you still getting the old column name from `Record Reader` or upstream; if EL is used, then check whether `Schema Name, Table Name` etc values derived properly; the table DDL is committed/done properly in the database. Last resort - try restarting NiFi!

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde - it does. See "Table Schema Cache Size"

Comment: Sorry for my bad! So did you try changing `Table Schema Cache Size` to 0?

Comment: Yes and not only that. I haven't tried restarting NiFi - but even if this option works - I don't believe this is the acceptable solution. There must be a way to clear cache - otherwise this is possible a defect.

Comment: With me also this has happened several times but with `DistributedMapCache` controller service!

Comment: @oceansize Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm trying to find out how to clear the cache.

Comment: @edjm By that time - no.